# Adjacent Letter Test

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

One aspect of password strength testing is runs of adjacent letters on the keyboard. In this challenge, a program must be created that returns `true` if a string contains any runs of adjacent letters.

### What counts as a run of adjacent letters?

For this simplified version of a password strength tester, a run of adjacent characters is 3 or more letters which are next to each other in a single direction (left, right, above or below) on a QWERTY keyboard. For the purpose of this challenge the layout of the keyboard looks like this:

```
1234567890
QWERTYUIOP
ASDFGHJKL
ZXCVBNM
```

In the diagram above `Q` is below `1` but not below `2`, so a string that contains `1qa` or `aq1` anywhere inside it would make the program return `true`, but `2qa` would not.

### Input

The password string to check. It will only contain the characters `[0-9a-z]` or `[0-9A-Z]` (your choice).

### Output

The program must return a truthy value if the password contains one or more runs of adjacent keys, or falsey if it contains none.

### Examples

The following inputs should output true:

- `asd`
- `ytrewq`
- `ju7`
- `abc6yhdef`

And these inputs should output false:

- `abc`
- `aaa`
- `qewretry`
- `zse`
- `qwdfbn`
- `pas`

### Rules

- Answers may be complete programs or functions.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score (in bytes) wins!

Comment: Duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48406/is-the-word-typeable-with-keys-adjacent-to-each-other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

Pretty straightforward approach. Checks if any of substrings len 3 are in any of the rotations of the keyboard. Will be using base encoding for keyboard.

```
.E}Rjb+J+Kc+jkS9"0
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm"b.tKN_MJ.:z3
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.E%7DRjb%2BJ%2BKc%2BjkS9%220%0Aqwertyuiop%0Aasdfghjkl%0Azxcvbnm%22b.tKN_MJ.%3Az3&input=asd&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=asd%0Aytrewq%0Aju7%0Aabc6yhdef%0Aabc%0Aaaa%0Aqewretry%0Azse%0Aqwdfbn%0Apas&debug=0).

Comment: @user81655 fixed, *and* saved two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 78 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
V=1oA ¬+`0\nqØÆyuiop\n?dfghjkl \nzxcvbnm`;1+¡Y©(((VbX -VbUgY-1)-5 a -5 %A a)bB
```

Outputs `0` for falsey cases; otherwise, a positive integer. The `?` should be replaced with the unprintable Unicode char U+0086, or if you don't want to go to all that trouble, just `as`.

#### How it works

```
V=1oA q +"0\nqwertyuiop\nasdfghjkl \nzxcvbnm";1+Um@Y&&(((VbX -VbUgY-1)-5 a -5 %A a)bB
           // Implicit: U = input string
V=1oA q    // Set variable V to the digits 1-9, plus
+"...";    // this string.
Um@        // Take U and map each character X and its index Y with this function:
Y&&        //  If Y is 0, return Y; otherwise,
VbX -      //  take the index of X in V, subtract
VbUgY-1    //  the index of (char at position Y - 1 in U) in V,
-5 a -5    //  subtract 5, take the absolute value, subtract 5 again,
%A a       //  take modulo by 10, then take the absolute value.
           //  This returns 1 for any pair of characters that is adjacent
           //  within V, horizontally or vertically.
bB +1      // Take the index of 11 in the result and add one.
           // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 227

```
int h(string k){var q="1234567890,QWERTYUIOP,ASDFGHJKL,ZXCVBNM,1QAZ,2WSX,3EDC,4RFV,5TGB,6YHN,7UJM,8IK,9OL,";int i=0,j=0;for(;i<k.Length-2;i++)if((q+String.Concat(Enumerable.Reverse(q))).Contains(k.Substring(i,3)))j=1;return j;}
```

0 is falsey, 1 is truthy.
Concatenated all keys horizontal and vertical, and reversed, and checks if any of 3 chars of input is contained within.

C# is really verbose, gotta dive into other languages :(

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 173+1 bytes

```php
while(~$argn[$i+2])($p=preg_match)($r=_.join(".{10}",str_split(($t=substr($argn,$i++,3))))."|$t"._,$d=_1234567890_qwertyuiop_asdfghjkl__zxcvbnm)||$p($r,strrev($d))?die(1):0;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` with lowercase input or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27fe1d84d61b3c3d0e1690da075118d8be89ab2f).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 156 bytes

```
#(some(set(for[R[["1234567890""QWERTYUIOP""ASDFGHJKL.""ZXCVBNM..."]]R[R(apply map list R)]r R p(partition 3 1 r)p((juxt seq reverse)p)]p))(partition 3 1 %))
```

This was a quite interesting task to implement.